# Angular: custom keyboard action

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In a textarea, i want to customize the line break action. the default behavior is defined by click on enter, i want to program the line break action to be done when i click on Alt+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `(keydown.alt.enter)` and `(keydown.enter)` events. If your textarea is using [(ngModel)] you can has some like

```
<textarea #textArea #textAreaModel="ngModel" 
     [(ngModel)]="value" 
     (keydown.alt.enter)="altEnter(textArea,textAreaModel)"
     (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault();enter()">
</textarea>
```

See that you pass to the function "altEnter" the "textArea" (the HTMLElement) and the "textAreaModel" (the "model")

If you use ReactiveForms you can has some like

```
<textarea #textArea [formControl]="control" 
      (keydown.alt.enter)="altEnter(textArea,control)"
      (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault();enter()">
</textarea>
```

See that in this case you pass to the function the "textArea" (the HTMLElement) and the formControl "control"

Your functions are like

```
  enter(){
    console.log("enter")
  }
  altEnter(element:any,control:any){
    const start=element.selectionStart; //get teh Selection start and end
    const end=element.selectionEnd;
    let value:string[]=element.value.split('')
    value.splice(start,end-start,'\n')
    if (control.control)
      control.control.setValue(value.join(''))  //give value to the ngModel
    else
      control.setValue(value.join(''))   //give value to the formControl
    setTimeout(()=>{
      element.selectionStart=element.selectionEnd=start+1 //position the cursor
    })
  }
```

You can see both cases in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-deiasi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)